# Why stdClass and anonymous class behave differently when in assertEquals()?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In phpunit

```php
$this->assertEquals((object)[], (object)[]); 
//and
$this->assertEquals(new stdClass(), new stdClass());
```

is ok, but

```php
$this->assertEquals(new class{}, new class{});
```

fails. 
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are two different classes. Each `new class{}` instruction generates a separate class definition.

```
$one = new class{};
$two = new class{};
var_dump(get_class($one), get_class($two));
```

Output:

```
string(39) "class@anonymous/in/FULlj0x7fc9081ac018"
string(39) "class@anonymous/in/FULlj0x7fc9081ac02c"
```

Only instances of anonymous classes create by the same instruction in your code will share the class:

```
function createClass() {
  return new class{};
}
$one = createClass();
$two = createClass();
var_dump(get_class($one), get_class($two));
```

Output:

```
string(39) "class@anonymous/in/sbApQ0x7f3138fe3089" 
string(39) "class@anonymous/in/sbApQ0x7f3138fe3089"
```